# Create Event Graph 2.1

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

according to the [Upgrading guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading/) creating event thru Graph API will be deprecated

Is there a new way to create an Event?

maybe with redirect to the Facebook iOS app is some way?

Comment: No, there is no way to create events via API from v2 on; and they are not planing to add that functionality back again as of now.

Comment: I guess after the 4/30/2014 it will be out of use :(